# Unable to send from outlook email account synced on phone, error - Unable to sign or encrypt message. Certificate not installed

Tags: email, samsung-galaxy-s-3, exchange, outlook

I have my work outlook account synced on my Samsung. For the first month, sending and receiving emails from my phone worked fine. Currently, I am able to receive emails but when I try to send them I get the error "Unable to sign or encrypt message. Certificate not installed" and I can no longer send on my account.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: There's a known issue on Samsung devices. Please see here: http://webcazine.com/7630/how-to-solve-unable-to-sign-or-encrypt-message-certificate-not-installed-error-on-galaxy-s4/